# Can one call an inheritng superclass's method overridden by a interface "default" from the interface?

Tags: java, inheritance

I did looked at the suggested possible duplicates.  They don't ask this but related things.

I have this desired structure in Java 8:

```
class BaseClass {
   int method(int arg) {...}  // does 99% of the work
}

interface MixinInterface { // intended only for subclasses of BaseClass

   default int method(int arg) {
        // what I want:
        // effectively Subclass.super.method(arg) 
        int ret = this.super.method(arg);
        { do some embellishment on super.method results }
        return(ret);
   }

}

class Subclass
    extends BaseClass
    implements MixinInterface
{
}
```

Yes one can do this with Reflection or add a callSuperMethod() method to the interface inheriting class but it is either real slow or messy. Via reflection it would be, find the superclass of the object inheriting the interface (and thus having it's "super.method" overridden by the interface's default), get the method handle from the superclass "class" and invoke it.

Comment: Given that `BaseClass` and `MixinInterface` both have the same signature for `method()`, I'm intrigued as to why you have chosen to use a mixin interface. Is there a particular reason for this? (Given that you could achieve what you want by simply over-riding `method()` in `SubClass`.)

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve. Since `BaseClass` already provides a method `method`, the default method implementation in the interface will never be invoked for any `Subclass` instance. There's no point even in trying to invoke the same method on the superclass from a default method, since, if the method is available on the superclass, the default method is ignored.

Comment: You shouldn't, but if you must you can  add `  BaseClass getBaseClass();` to the interface and use it in the interface default `method` by `getBaseClass().method(arg); `

Comment: The point is to add "Mixin" capability so overridable behaviors can be added to a base class by adding interfaces.  In the Base class you could override a method in the interface but the interface could still access the supreclass method of the base it was attached to so the base class could have "most of the meat" of the function and the interface class could add nuance to a specific behavior or a BaseClass subclass.  Which itself could override the method and still access the interface default which has access to it's base class's super method.  Enabling amost dynamc language static mixins.

Comment: The point of the above is to enable "composing" behaviors of a base class by selecting from a library of interfaces designed for that base class containing various behaviors.  Like using the ruby "include" mechanism.

Similar to what C++ templates allow but in the easier to manage java environment..

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can't have the same method signature in the interface and the baseclass and still use both independently, even with reflections thats tricky you need to resort `MethodHandles`.

One option is remove the extends BaseClass and doing something similar to a decorator pattern.

```
class BaseClass {
   int method(int arg) {...}  // does 99% of the work
}

interface MixinInterface { // intended only for subclasses of BaseClass

   default int method(int arg) {
        // what I want:
        // effectively Subclass.super.method(arg) 
        int ret = getBaseClass().method(arg);

        return(ret);
   }

   BaseClass getBaseClass();

}

class Subclass implements MixinInterface
{
    private final BaseClass baseClass;

    public Subclass(BaseClass baseClass) {
        this.baseClass = baseClass;
    }

    @Override
    public BaseClass getBaseClass() {
        return baseClass;
    }

   // forward other method calls to baseClass (can be included in the MixinInterface as well)

}
```

Another option rename the decorator method and use it in `BaseCase`, that way the `implements MixinInterface` is almost superfluous and should be replaced with a static method call (especially if you only have one decorated method). Decorator chaining will not be easily possible with this one.

```
abstract class BaseClass {

    abstract int methodDecorator(int originalReturn);

    int method(int arg) {
        // do 99% of the work
        return methodDecorator(0);
    } 
}

interface MixinInterface {
    default int methodDecorator(int arg) {
        return arg;
    }
}

class Subclass extends BaseClass implements MixinInterface {
    @Override
    public int methodDecorator(int originalReturn) {
        // Sadly you need this forwarding, making this approach a bit clunky
        return MixinInterface.super.methodDecorator(originalReturn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep there are way to do it which I have done, just not simple language integrated ways where one doesn;t either have to modify the base classes, or use reflection method handles.  For items where small atom performance not an issue using a dynamic dispatch convenience function works.  But having a 

BaseClass.this.super.superMethod()   built into the languange that does.
cast interfaces' this to BaseClass get super of base class, dispatch call to superclasses method for BaseClass woudl be a very very handy thing to have and less baroque that dynamic dispatch helper utilitites.

Comment: The performance/elegance of a none working solution is irrelevant. You need to stick to things that actually work in java or change the language.

Comment: as is true with anything but someone might be aware of a working technique I am not aware of so I ask, partly to find out, partly to posit the desire for it.